# How to render Arabic characters by creating a temp HTML input file and send it to wkhtmltopdf engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have tried all the scripts and methods to show arabic character in wkhtmltopdf  when pass string to wkhtml instead of url but unable to show.So I read different forums and found a soluntion but i dont have any idea about
How to render Arabic characters by creating a temp HTML input file and send it to wkhtmltopdf engine.I want to show arabic characters in pdf through  wkhtmltopdf.
So how can I do it.

Comment: Where do you have problems with it? Is it that creating the file is a problem or feeding that file to wkhtmltopdf is the problem? Or something else? Can you show us how you tried to create the file and how you tried to feed it to wkhtmltopdf? Or is it that you don't know where to start?

Comment: Problem solved.I am creating HTML file in folder and pass this file to wkhtml through string

Comment: That's nice. It'd be really cool if you would add the solution here as well as the answer to this question.